# Winform Tooltip issue

Tags: c#, winforms

in my application i want to add Tool-tips.
after configure the tool tip i want the option to distinguished between the label who activate the Tool tip in order to show the appropriate text so in the Tool tip function i am try to do it but got an error: **"The type 'Accessibility.IAccessible' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"**

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
    string st = e.AssociatedControl.AccessibilityObject.Parent.Name;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply go for e.AssociatedControl.Name ?

Comment: Did you try adding a reference to the assembly it tells you to? (Accessibility)

Comment: I guess the question is whether he needs to get a reference to the AccessibleObject, or not.

Comment: e.AssociatedControl.Name works fine, thanks ! BTW if i want to add new string into my Tool tip via toolTip1_Popup function, how can i do it (i only found Tool tip title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.accessibilityobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
`To get or set the AccessibilityObject property, you must add a reference to the 
 Accessibility assembly installed with the .NET Framework`
```

So you just need to add this reference using the project references.

Of course the [PopupEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.popupeventargs.aspx) contains the control for which the tooltip is drawn and thus you could simply use `e.AssociatedControl.Name`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reference the AccessibleObject. All you need is get the name of the AssociatedControl, like so:

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
    string st = e.AssociatedControl.Name;
}
```

As for your subquestion, to set the tooltip text dinamically you could try something like this:

```
        private bool recursing;
        private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
        {
            Control c = e.AssociatedControl as Control;
            if (c != null)
            {
                if (!recursing)
                {
                    recursing = true;
                    toolTip1.SetToolTip(c, "totototo");
                    recursing = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Note that we have to use a flag because calling SetToolTip will cause the PopUp event to be fired again

Cheers